# SCPI 34970A Connection Exception

Tags: c#, dll, exception, driver

I have tried writing this question on Keysights community page, but apparently they have a lack of community. I am hoping there will be individuals here that can help me, however.

Anyways, I have written a program that talks to an Agilent 34970A roughly every minute (variable depending on input values, and also random depending on input values) and scans through almost 20 channels. I then parse all the data and make sure everything looks right. I have run into several issues, and I have worked through most of them, however, I am now stuck with one.

SOMETIMES, I get an exception when I first try to connect to the instrument. The short version of the exception is:

```
Keysight.CommandExpert.InstrumentAbstraction.CommunicationTimeoutException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233088
Message=Timed out while trying to query instrument errors
Source=Keysight.CommandExpert.Scpi
Timeout=10000
```

I have written my code in C#, and like I said it happen right when I try to connect to the instrument. This line of code is:
Ag3497x v34970A = new Ag3497x("ASRL1::INSTR");
How do I handle this exception? Originally I was using IVI-COM drivers, but found them to be cumbersome and unreliable. I read on here somewhere one person who preferred the SCPI commands, so I switched to these. However, when I was using the IVI drivers, there was a command to close the connection. I couldn't find on with the SCPI commands. Could this be part of the issue?

The full code I use to talk with and read data from the 34970A is as follows:
string readings = null;

```
Ag3497x v34970A = new Ag3497x("ASRL1::INSTR");
v34970A.SCPI.RST.Command();
v34970A.SCPI.DISPlay.TEXT.Command("CYCLE TESTER");
v34970A.Transport.DefaultTimeout.Set(-1);
v34970A.SCPI.CONFigure.VOLTage.AC.Command(100, "MAX", "@101:116");
v34970A.SCPI.SENSe.VOLTage.AC.BANDwidth.Command(1000, "@101:117");
v34970A.SCPI.CONFigure.VOLTage.AC.Command(10, "MAX", "@117");
v34970A.SCPI.SENSe.VOLTage.AC.BANDwidth.Command(1000, "@117");
v34970A.SCPI.CONFigure.VOLTage.AC.Command(300, "MAX", "@119");
v34970A.SCPI.SENSe.VOLTage.AC.BANDwidth.Command(60, "@119");
v34970A.SCPI.CONFigure.TEMPerature.Command("TCouple", "K", 1, "MAX", "@118");
v34970A.SCPI.ROUTe.SCAN.Command("@101:119");
v34970A.SCPI.TRIGger.COUNt.Command(1);
v34970A.SCPI.READ.QueryAllData(null, out readings);
```

I run this code up to 10,000 times as required by the test the program is written for. I am connective via SERIAL as you can see in the code.

Anyways, any help would be much appreciated. As am sure you could understand, when a program fails at cycle 8000 out of 10000, it can be very frustrated, especially when 10000 cycles can take more than 10 days to complete. Really, maybe I'll get lucky and someone will know how I can prevent this, but I'm truly looking for a way to handle this exception when it does happen, assuming it can't be prevented. ***So really, this long post is asking how to handle an exception.*** I have searched, but this answer has alluded me. If you would like to know any other detail, please let me know, and I will provide it promptly.

Thanks again,

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few suggestions:

- Why do you have to call the `Ag3497x` constructor on each iteration? construct the device only once and reuse it.
- What are the baud rate? cable length? consider shorter cables and smaller baud rate.
- Consider sniffing out what exactly happening in the port while this exception is happening using some serial port sniffer like [this one](http://freeserialanalyzer.com/).
- If everything else is fine and it seems like some issue within the Visa driver, if you don't have some response from Keysights, consider using a different visa driver or implement your own using [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx).